# Canonical forms in Maxima

Tags: maxima, canonicalization

#### Background

While working in Maxima I got two expressions I knew were equivalent, but Maxima did not think so.

<sup>*(This started out as a question about floating point accuracy in Maxima, but I got stuck on something slightly more fundamental: how to make sure expressions are "normalized", if that is even possible.)*</sup>

#### Problem session

While solving an equation using `solve()` I got an answer (`a`) involving rationals and rational exponents. I also had a "reference solution" (`b`) in another form. It is not obvious from inspection that these numbers are identical:

```
(%i1) a:(311647*2181529^(1/5))/(63360*17424^(1/5))$
(%i2) b:(7^(7/5)*211^(12/5))/(40*11^(7/5)*12^(12/5))$
```

I wanted to see if they were, so I tried a few things:

```
(%i3) a=b,pred;
(%o3)                                false
(%i4) a-b,numer;
(%o4)                         1.4210854715202E-14
(%i5) ratsimp(a-b);
                      2/5   2/5        1/5    7/5    12/5      1/5
             311647 11    12    2181529    - 7    211     17424
(%o5)        -----------------------------------------------------
                                7/5   12/5      1/5
                           40 11    12     17424
```

Wow, that's a mouthful! Obviously I've done something wrong, but I'm not giving up. I'm trying different things until I find:

```
(%i6) radcan(a-b);
(%o6)                                  0
(%i7) radcan(a)=radcan(b),pred;
(%o7)                               true
```

Bingo! `radcan()` managed to convert it to a canonical form, which could then be further simplified.

#### Question

`radcan()` was necessary in this case because the expression involved radicals, but at first I did not know that - when developing something you don't always know in which form the solution is. Is there a standard set of functions that one can apply, to "canonicalize" a *generic* expression in Maxima, or am I abusing Maxima here?